# How do I prevent a parallel for loop in python from accessing the same folder twice?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am writing a python program that runs an external model *in parallel* a certain number of times to define data in a parameter space. Because of how the external model is written (for good reasons I promise), I have to make a new copy of the model folder if I want to run it at the same time. I made the copies of my main model folder foo, and called them foo0, foo1, foo2, and foo3. Now I want to be able to go into the specific directory based on the thread, make some changes, run the model, write to a main file, and then move to the next run. Each model run can take between 30s to 200s, hence the benefit of parallel vs serial runs.

```
import subprocess
from joblib import Parallel

def run_model(base_path):
    #Make some changes using a random number generator in the folder
    ....
    #Run the model using bash on windows. Note the str(threading.get_ident()) is my
    #attempt to get the thread 0,1,2,3
    subprocess.run(['bash','-c', base_path + str(threading.get_ident()) + '/Model.exe'])
    #Write some input for the run to a main file that will store all runs
    with open('Inputs.txt','a') as file:
        with open(base_path + str(threading.get_ident()) + '/inp.txt') as inp_file:
            for i,line in enumerate(inp_file):
                if i == 5:
                    file.write(line)

Parallel(n_jobs=4, backend="threading")(run_model('Models/foo') for i in range(0,10000))
```

However, I keep getting the FileNotFoundError since the thread id keeps changing and the folder does not exist. The model is large so copying the model with a new thread id (something like a folder named foo+thread_id) is both slow and uses a lot of disk space. Is there any way I can limit only a certain copy of a model to run on a certain thread making sure it is not being used by any other thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just dedicate a process to each directory:

```
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def run_model(base_path, iterations, output_lock):
    for x in range(iterations):
        #Make some changes using a random number generator in the folder
        ...
        #Run the model using bash on windows.
        subprocess.run(['bash','-c', base_path + '/Model.exe'])
        #Write some input for the run to a main file that will store all runs
        with output_lock:
            with open('Inputs.txt','a') as out_file:
                with open(base_path + '/inp.txt') as inp_file:
                    for i,line in enumerate(inp_file):
                        if i == 5:
                            out_file.write(line)

N = 4
total_runs = 10000
process_list = list()
output_lock = Lock()
for x in range(N):
    arguments = ("Models/foo%s" % x, int(total_runs / N), output_lock)
    p = Process(target=run_model, args=arguments)
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    process_list.append(p)
for p in process_list:
    p.join()
```

I took the liberty of renaming the output file handle so that it doesn't overwrite the built-in `file` class. Also, I added a lock to protect the output file.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a lot. I changed 'for x in iterations:' to 'for x in range(iterations):' and cast total_runs/N to an int, but thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad it worked, but after thinking about it, I think you could use `joblib.Parallel` and use `"Models/foo%s" % (i % 4)` to pass the directory name.

Answer (score 2):

You could structure your program like so:

1. First, the main thread searches for folders that need to be processed, and places them into a thread-safe Queue. During this phase, you ensure that the queue contains only unique items. A synchronization primitive is used around the queue to make sure that only one thing is accessing it at a time.
2. Worker threads are started
3. Worker threads dequeue work from the syncrhonized thread-safe queue, and process them.
4. Threads join when there is no work left in the queue
5. When all threads are joined, work is done.

The picture of this is like:

```
   Queue of unique dirs is constructed.
                  ||
                  \/            Consumer 0
                              /
                             / /Consumer 1
Queue(DirD->DirC->DirB->DirA)    ...
                             \ \Consumer i
                  ||          \  ...
                  \/            Consumer n

           Dirs are processed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not rely on `threading.get_ident()` in most cases except for one: telling that if two thread instances are actually the same one.  However, the original implementation is unluckily not the only legal case and that's why it got into a mess.

Try to refit the call to `run_model('Models/foo')` to another form, such as:

```
    run_model('Models/foo', i%4)
    run_model('Models{}/foo'.format(i%4))
```

depending by favor.  Then modify the body in `run_model()` to utilize this new parameter to create the thread-workers you need.  I think that should solve the problem mostly.

But more than that, your code body lacks synchronization.  You need some `lock()` or `wait()` mechanisms between the invocations of new threads or you'll get into another mess, e.g. 10,000 threads created at once or 2,500 threads accessing the same file. :)